# ¿Como verificar si un datos ya esta registrado en la base de datos y sino seguir comparando los demás?

Tags: java, mysql

Hola estoy tratando de registrar datos desde un archivo de excel pero cuando encuentra un datos ya existente manda un error. Como puedo hacer para que cuando un dato ya este registrado siga verificando los demás y los registre si no se encuentran en la BD.

Este es el código que utilizo

```
public class Seleccion {

Conexion con;
String idQuery;
String nombrePag;
String fechaAcceso;

JFileChooser selector = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

public File Abrir(Component parent) {
    selector.setDialogTitle("Abrir archivo de excel");
    File f;
    int returnVal = selector.showOpenDialog(parent);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = selector.getSelectedFile();
        f = file;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return f;
}

public void LeerArchivosExcel(String archivoDestino) {
    int contador = 1;
    try {
        Workbook archivoExcel = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(archivoDestino));
        //Recore cada hoja 
        Conexion1 con = new Conexion1();
        Connection cn = con.Conectar();
        for (int hojas = 0; hojas < archivoExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); hojas++) {
            Sheet hoja = archivoExcel.getSheet(hojas);
            int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
            int numFilas = hoja.getRows();
            String dato;

            //Recorre cada fila de la hoja
            for (int fila = 0; fila < numFilas; fila++) {
                for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) {
                    dato = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();
                    System.out.println(dato + " ");
                    //instruccion switch que evalua la variable contador
                    switch (contador) {
                        case 1:
                            idQuery = dato;
                            contador++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            nombrePag = dato;
                            contador++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            fechaAcceso = dato;
                            contador = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\n");

                //
                String sentencia = "INSERT INTO datosquery (`idQuery`,`nombrePag`,`fechaAcceso`) VALUES ('" + idQuery + "','" + nombrePag + "','" + fechaAcceso + "')";
                PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sentencia);
                pst.executeUpdate();

            }
            con.cerrarConexion();
        }
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: has intentado asigando propiedades unique a los campos?

Comment: el campo idQuery es unique. Lo que quiero es que cuando encuentre un dato ya registrado mi programa no se detenga sino que siga verificando los demas datos del archivo de excel

Answer (score 1):

En mysql existe la sentencia `INSERT IGNORE` que ignora los registros que no se pueden insertar y sigue con la inserción de los demás

Solo tendrías que cambiar

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO datosquery (`idQuery`,`nombrePag`,`fechaAcceso`) VALUES ('" + idQuery + "','" + nombrePag + "','" + fechaAcceso + "')"
```

te dejo la [documentación del INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: La respuesta es valida, pero es una invitacion a obviar cualquier otro tipo de error que tambien ocurra no relacionado con este problema en particular.